# Consulta em SQL para Agrupar Registros no MS-ACCESS

Tags: sql, query, microsoft-access

Olá, gostaria de um comando em SQL para uma consulta em um banco de dados do *Access*.
A estrutura da tabela é:
***tbList***

```
Id | Nome | Genero | Endereco | Estado | ...
```

O resultado que gostaria fosse agrupar por estado e contar a quantidade de gêneros *(sexo)* desta maneira:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| ESTADO    | FEMININO | MASCULINO |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| SP        |       36 |        40 |
| RJ        |       44 |        13 |
| MG        |       17 |        23 |
...
...
```

Agradeço desde já, pela atenção de todos!

PS.: Desculpe por qualquer coisa de errado que eu tenha cometido, mas ainda estou aprendendo a utilizar o **stackoverflow**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que esta sintaxe é aceite em **MS-ACCESS**:

```
SELECT      Estado
        ,   SUM(IIF(Genero = 'F', 1, 0)) AS FEMININO
        ,   SUM(IIF(Genero = 'M', 1, 0)) AS MASCULINO
FROM        tbList
GROUP BY    Estado
```

Parti do princípio que na coluna `Genero` estavam os valores `'F'` e `'M'`, caso contrário basta alterar para os valores reais.

Comment: Obrigado! Era isso mesmo!